# How do I center images in css grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center images in css grid and also make the image cover the whole container. Here is the html and css code,

```css
.object-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(45, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(60, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0px;
  max-width: 550px;
  max-height: 720px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.object-wrapper div {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 5px;
  max-width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.001px solid whitesmoke;
  font-size: 5px;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="object">
  <div class="object-wrapper">
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="troll.jpg"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
```

When it displays the images appear in the middle of the intersections of the grid.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take away the max-height/width of your div and set display of your wrapper to `display: inline-grid`

Link to more on [`CSS Grid`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

example with comments below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .object-wrapper {
            /*display inline-grid*/
            display: inline-grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(45, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(60, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 0px;
            max-width: 550px;
            max-height: 720px;
        }

        .object-wrapper div {
            background: transparent;
            text-align: center;
            border: 0.001px solid whitesmoke;
            font-size: 5px;
        }

        img {
            max-height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            object-fit: cover;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="object">
    <div class="object-wrapper">
        <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
        <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
        <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
     <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
     <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
     <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
     <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
     <div><img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks so much, worked for the centering part! I'm wondering do you know how to make the image cover the entire box?

Comment: take away the padding. updated code.